# Simulate CDF curve for penetration/adoption extrapolation

Tags: normal-distribution, python, cumulative-distribution-function, extrapolation

I'd like to be able to plot a line like the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for the normal distribution, because it's useful for simulating the adoption curve:

[image: Adoption curve]

Specifically, I'd like to be able to use initial data (percentage adoption of a product) to extrapolate what the rest of that curve would look like, to give a rough estimate of the timeline to each of the phases.

So, for example, if we got to 10% penetration by 30 days and 20% penetration by 40 days, and we try to fit this curve, I'd like to know when we're going to get to 80% penetration (vs another population that may have taken 50 days to get to 10% penetration).

So, my question is, how could I go about doing this? I would ideally be able to provide initial data (time and penetration), and use Python to plot out the rest of the chart for me. But I don't know where to start! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See also my approach at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66303702/12046409)

Comment: In Python, you can use Scipy optimize.curve_fit routine and fit your data to a logistic function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). You can find an huge amount of examples on how to do this, just do it with your data and the logistic function. Literally 3 to 4 lines of code. (See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160803/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-for-logistic-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem ressembles that of [isotonic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression) in which a weighted least-squares penalty is optimized over non-decreasing functions. To be more specific, you seem to have only the red points in this figure:

[image: ecdf]

On my example running the default `sklearn.isotonic.IsotonicRegression` of scikit-learn, I get the following

[image: ecdf_iso]

Now if I instead use [linear interpolation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), I get the following:

[image: ecdf_lerp]

Finally, If you **know** your data is approximately gaussian (you mention the gaussian example), you can simply [use scipy's curve fitting routine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355296/how-do-i-estimate-the-right-parameters-for-a-cumulative-gaussian-fit) to approximate the CDF. In my case, I get the curve below:

[image: ecdf_gauss]

The fact it doesn't perfectly fit is because **my data is not gaussian**. You should try these techniques yourself and decide based on the results.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you so much—I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad you found this useful :)